# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{n + 1} \log(1/n + 1) \sin(1/n)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

What's the convergence of this series?

Due to the fact that:

- $\sin(1/n) \sim (1/n)$
- $\sqrt{n+1} \sim \sqrt{n}$
- $\log(1/n + 1) \sim e^{1/n}$

I think my general term is equivalent to $e^{1/n}/n^{1/2}$ but i can't do a useful comparison test with this result...

Comment: The last equivalence is certainly false. $log (1+\frac 1 n ) \to 0$ but $e^{\frac 1 n} \to 1$.

Comment: $\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)\le\frac1n$ and $\sin\left(\frac1n\right)\le\frac1n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sin (\frac 1 n)$ behaves like $\frac 1 n$ and $\log(1+\frac 1 n)$ also behaves like $\frac  1 n$. So compare with $\sum \frac 1 {n^{1.5}}$ and conclude that the series is absolutely convergent.